# localhost not loading correctly

Tags: apache-http-server, localhost, phpmyadmin

PhpMyAdmin is not loading correctly after XAMPP starts. I am using the default settings Apache running on ports 80 and 443 and MySQL port 3306. When launch it from XAMPP the page can't be loaded "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET". I'm using MS Edge as my browser but have tried Chrome and Firefox but neither work. I can access it from another PC on my network but not the one it has been installed on using this computers IP address (http://192.168.20.17/phpmyadmin/).

In addition if you load up the default http://localhost/dashboard/ the page takes forever to load and it only loads the text and images but not the CSS or JavaScript files. When you type these in the browser for example http://localhost/dashboard/stylesheets/normalize.css it will load straight away.

I have tried following with no success

- Using the web address of http://localhost:8080, http://127.0.0.1/ and even used my pc's IP address for this PC.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling XAMPP
- Turning off the firewall then restarting XAMPP
- Resetting winsock "netsh winsock reset"
- ipconfig /flushdns
- Cleared the browser cache
- Reinstalled the all browsers (chrome, firefox, ms edge)

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily fixed by changing the port number in the ttpd.conf file from XAMPP

1. Replaced "Listen 80" with "Listen 8015"
2. Replaced "ServerName localhost:80" with "ServerName localhost:8015"
3. Stopped both Apache and MySQL in XAMPP then restarted them both

Instead of using the address of http://localhost/ replaced it with http://localhost:8015/ and works just fine.

However, when you go Apache or MySQL from XAMPP it you need to manually add the ":8015" at the end to allow it to work.